# Assistance required with Powershell Script pls

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script which searches a list of computers/servers and identifies if a user profile exists for each member of an AD group called 'TestDisabledUsers'. Results are then piped to a CSV file with the format below.

```
ComputerName    WMI_Connection  Pingable    Profile_Search
Computer1   Server IS Contactable   TRUE    User1 Exists ; User2 Exists ; User3 No Profile
Computer2   Server IS Contactable   TRUE    User1 No Profile ; User2 Exists ; User3 Exists
Computer3   Server IS Contactable   TRUE    User1 Exists ; User2 Exists ; User3 No Profile
```

Current script is not working at present as it only shows 1 user in the `Profile_Search` output :-(

Apologies if this is a simple solution, I'm not the best coder ;-) Any help very much appreciated.

So far I have the following powershell script :-

```
    Clear-History
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'

$outputFolderName = 'ProfileAudit ' + $(Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy)
$outputpath = "C:\temp\$outputFolderName"
If(!(test-path $outputpath))
{
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $outputpath | out-null
}

$computers = Get-Content -path C:\Temp\svrs.txt

$report = @()

foreach ($computer in $computers) {

$Ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -count 2
$wmi = gwmi win32_bios -ComputerName $computer

if ($wmi)
{
$WMIResult = 'Server IS Contactable'

$profiles = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity TestDisabledUsers | Foreach {$_.SamAccountName}

foreach ($profile in $profiles) {

$user = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq $profile }

if ($user)
{
$profileexists = ("$profile Exists") -join ' ; '
#$user | Remove-CimInstance
}
else {
$profileexists = ("$profile No Profile") -join ' ; '
}
}

$tempreport  = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
$tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name WMI_Connection -Value $WMIResult
$tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Pingable -Value $Ping
$tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Profile_Search -Value $profileexists
$report += $tempreport
}
else
{
$WMIResult = 'Server NOT Contactable'

$tempreport = New-Object PSObject
$tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
$tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name WMI_Connection -Value $WMIResult
$tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Pingable -Value $Ping
$tempreport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Profile_Search -Value $null
$report += $tempreport
}
}

$CSVFileName = 'ProfileAudit ' + $(Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy) + '.csv'
$report | Export-Csv $outputpath\$CSVFileName -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below. The main issue is that you're overwriting $profileexists instead of appending to it in the profile loop.

```
Clear-History

$outputpath = "C:\temp\ProfileAudit $(Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy)"
If(!(test-path $outputpath))
{
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $outputpath | out-null
}

$report = Get-Content -path C:\Temp\svrs.txt | % {

    $ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -count 2
    $profileexists = $null

    if(gwmi win32_bios -ComputerName $_)
    {
        $WMIResult = 'Server IS Contactable'
        $profiles = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity TestDisabledUsers | select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
        foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
            
            $user = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $_ -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq $profile }
            if ($user)
            {
                $profileexists += "$profile Exists;"
            }
            else {
                $profileexists += "$profile No Profile;"
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $WMIResult = 'Server NOT Contactable'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
    ComputerName = $_.ToUpper()
    WMI_Connection = $WMIResult
    Pingable = $Ping
    Profile_Search = $profileexists
    }
}

$CSVFileName = 'ProfileAudit ' + $(Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy) + '.csv'
$report | Export-Csv $outputpath\$CSVFileName -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Awesomeness  - many thanks Mike. Worked a treat.  Thanks again for your time.